# What is the mechanism of gulp.browersync? Such as cssinject and sync-scroll for multiple browsers

Tags: html, css, browser-sync

gulp.browersync is like black magic to me. I want to understand the technique it used.

In css-injection, how does the browser know css file is changed? Why can it redraw the page without refresh? Why is it not the case for .html/.js update?

When there are multiple browsers open the sync-ed page, if scroll down in one, others follow. Why? What actions can be sync-ed, and what not? It is really amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understading Browsersync is a service that does a few things...

The black magic occurs when it injects a Javascript file in your page (see the source code of your page). How? It's listening connections in a specific port (creating a proxy server) and then modifiying your page.

The injected JS listens to the commands that the service is sending, through techniques like web sockets... or simple async requests for older browsers I think...

For example, when you move your mouse, it send to the other pages a similar command to replicate the state...

Also Browsersync, if running, keeps watching the files you specify to watch, CSS files for example... and sends the needed commands if those files are changed.

Many automation tools like Grunt or Gulp could integrate with it to get the coolest development workflow you can imagine... Testing multiple devices, rebuilding caches and more...

And yes... it's like black magic :D

See Browsersync requests in action here: https://webmshare.com/ovwGg

Comment: Good explanation. Could you tell me why CSS modification can be applied to page without refresh the page? Does it relate to browser standard or some other black magic? I mean, I can use mouse to select/highlight some text in the page, then modify CSS to change font size, that text keeps in highlight state. It is not the case if refresh the whole page in HTML or JS modification. Why does browser treat CSS differently from HTML/JS update?

Comment: Thanks. Browsersync updates the stylesheets as required, so the user selection keeps intact as the html structure hasn't change at all. I will update my answer with a video of the network showing Browserync fetching the stylesheets so you can understand better what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to browsersync, what I found so far is listed below:

BrowserSync is an automation tool that makes web development faster.
BrowserSync lets you launch a local web server around the working directory so the target page and its related files can instantly be accessed on all devices connected to your home network by pointing them to a localhost URL. Furthermore, it supports live reloading, so any changes you make to the page or its CSS triggers a refresh of the browser on all connected devices for you to preview.

BrowserSync is like a LiveReload (it watches for changes you make to a web page and automatically updates the browser), except that it also works across multiple devices.

BrowserSync that being able to scroll inside one browser and see that action mirrored in all others.

The Action Sync feature (enabled by default) will copy scroll position, clicks and form inputs from one browser to all of the others that are connected.
Some useful links:

- https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-browsersync-for-faster-development

  http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/mobilefriendly2.shtml

  http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/test-your-sites-multiple-devices-81516496

I have one issue faced during working with browsersync, if anyone here interested to answer can visit the link: [How to sync the actions performed on webpage using Browsersync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39920069/how-to-sync-the-actions-performed-on-webpage-using-browsersync/39929310?noredirect=1#comment67362318_39929310).