# How to sync the actions performed on webpage using Browsersync?

Tags: browser-sync

I am an automation tester. I installed browser-sync globally to test the website we have. I tried with below code (in index.html file) for trial purpose.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://www.google.co.in/" onload="this.width=screen.width;this.height=screen.height"></iframe> 
    </body>
</html>
```

I had added an iframe to open the URL I want to open and resize it to default windows size. And CSS code call above is as below:

```css
        h1
        {
            background: red;
        }
```

gulf.js file code is as below:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bs = require('browser-sync').create();
// create a browser sync instance.
gulp.task('serve', function()
  {
  bs.init ({
   server: {
     baseDir: "Desktop/BrowserSync/Demo", index: "index.html"
    }
   });
gulp.watch("*.html").on('change', bs.reload);
});
```

It is just giving the background color as red.

It is opening the Google page for me on all browsers and configurations I have. When I tried for scroll movement vertically, the same has been performed on all the opened browser window.

However, when I tried to insert any text in Google search box or click or any link on Google home page, it is not syncing/executing these actions on other opened browser windows, not even horizontal scroll.

I am totally new to browser-sync. I also tried with some gulp.js file to resolve above issue. However no success, as while running it has given me an issue like cannot find browser-sync function and package.json  file is missing something like this.

Comment: Please Note: here I am just trying to perform cross browser, cross device testing for the website.
I just want to perform some action on my website and I want that the same action to be reflected on all other browsers where my webpage is opened through browser sync generated URL.
I am not going/intended to watch any css or html changes.

Answer (score 0):

Visit this link - https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp below the docs and copy the code below in **gulpfile.js** file outside your src folder

```
 var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Static server
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });
});

// or...

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "yourlocal.dev"
    });
});
```

create **package.json** file and check whether it has this code:-

```
"devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.15.0", //versions of the package
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2"
  }
```

Comment: I had already installed Browsersync globally by using command “npm install -g browser-sync” and gulp too.
But as per link given by you, it says that “First, you'll need to install Browsersync & Gulp as development dependencies” as “$ npm install browser-sync gulp --save-dev”
So do I need to uninstalled them and install again?
And one more Q., is it mandatory to install gulp and write gulp.js file always to sync the actions performed on webpage using Browsersyn ?

Comment: If it's not working try a fresh install of browsersync and gulp. Instead of gulp you can also try using grunt js. Here's the https://www.browsersync.io/docs/grunt . Good luck with that. :)

Comment: I had uninstalled browsersync and gulp which I installed globally.
I cross checked it as well as given below.
C:\Users\PPawar1\Desktop\BrowserSync\New Demo>browser-sync -version
'browser-sync' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\PPawar1\Desktop\BrowserSync\New Demo>gulp -version
'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: C:\Users\PPawar1\Desktop\BrowserSync\New Demo>npm install browser-sync gulp --sa
ve-dev
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher
 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.14
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher
 to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade
 to lodash@^4.0.0.

. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.

Comment: above issue i got when i tried to install it again as given in link provided by you

Comment: I think you have to update packages. Update all of them using command npm update -g . The install gulp and then browser-sync from scratch.

Comment: Please see my comment below the question I asked, will it be possible to achieve the way you answered? Do I really need to need to go through gulp, grunt or SASS to achieve action synchronization using browsersync?

Comment: Even after using npm update -g and then npm install browser-sync gulp --save-dev.
It is not allowing me to install Browsersync & Gulp as development dependencies.

Comment: Definitely, from browsersync, gulp/ grunt you can achieve what you wanted.

Comment: Most importantly have created package.json file which tells about the dependencies and version of npm packages. Check my answer I've added package JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing your package.json, you'll need to use 'npm init' in the root of your project. From there, if you have gulp installed globally ('npm install -g gulp' if you don't) you'll want to use 'npm install gulp browser-sync --save-dev' This command will download the required gulp and browser-sync dependencies. The '--save-dev' part adds them to your package.json.

Also, I noticed you said this is in your 'gulf.js' The file must be named 'gulpfile.js' unless you specifically change the file gulp is looking for. This is my first time answering something, so I hope it helps!